# How to bind enum to Switch control ? Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have switch control in my pcl and have a enum for the control. I am not sure how to bind the value of enum to the switch. If switch is off then, value is 0 and if switch is on, the value is 1. How can I bind it to the enum?

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <Label YAlign="Center"  Text="M "></Label>    
    <Switch x:Name="switchM" ></Switch>
</StackLayout>
```

Enum class

```
public enum mActive
{
    NotToggled = 0,
    Toggled = 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a value converter for this. The `IsToggled` property of the `Switch` only accepts a `bool` parameter, so you will have to convert your `Enum` type to a `bool`. Yours would look something along the lines of:

```
public class BoolToMyEnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is mActive)
        {
            return (mActive)value == 0 ? false : true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return (bool)value ? mActive.Toggled : mActive.NotToggled;
        }

        return mActive.NotToggled;
    }
}
```

Then ensure that on the page you're using this it can be found in XAML by adding a namespace declaration at the top:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters;assembly=MyApp"
```

When that's done you can add it to your Page's resource dictionary:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:BoolToMyEnumConverter x:Key="myConv" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </ContentPage.Resources>
```

In the binding for the Switch you can then specify:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding MyEnumInViewModel, Converter={StaticResource myConv}}" />
```

Which references a property in your View Model of type mActive. Keep in mind this is a rough draft of how it should work. I advise you to read up on Value Converters to help you further implement this.

```
public mActive MyEnumInViewModel {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thank you the thorough guide. I'll try now.